# How to use asynchronous calls for best performance

Tags: javascript, rest, asynchronous

In Django I have 3 models: Car, Driver, Company

```
class Company(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Driver(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Car(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    model_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    driver = models.ForeignKey(Driver, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

On the front end, I want to display a table with Cars and their drivers and the company the driver is from. I have a REST API that I query for this. So my first request goes to the `/api/cars`. This gives me a list of the cars and the driver id. Then in order to get the driver and company names I do follow up request with that id like so:

```
const cars = await axios.get('api/cars');

for (let i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
        const current = cars[i];
        const driver = await getDriver(current.driver);   //driver = {id: someID, name: someName, company: someCompany}
        current.driver = driver;
        const company = await getCompany(driver.company);
        current.company = company;
    }

return cars;
```

So What I am getting back is an array like so:

```
   [ 
    {
      id:someId, 
      model_name: someModelName, 
      driver: {
                id:someID, 
                name:someName, 
                company: { 
                           id:someID, 
                           name:someName
                          }
            }
    },
    ...
    ]
```

Unfortunately, I can't change anything on the REST API or the Database (MySQL). As it gets bigger, compiling the results take pretty long, so I was wondering if there is a faster way to use the async calls from the front end?

Comment: Make the requests in parallel by not using `await` inside a loop. Collect promises in an array, and use `Promise.all` to wait for the result. However, make sure not to overwhelm your API.

Comment: Is it someone else’s API or something? Because that’s a really big waste.

Comment: it is unfortnuately